# openjdk8: download from Mercurial using hg

Tags: mercurial, solaris-10, openjdk-8

I am trying to download openjdk8 source code from Mercurial repository using

```
hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8 openJDK8
```

Am getting the below error:

> abort: error: node name or service name not known

If we add the ipaddress and hostname to `/etc/hosts` file, will it get resolved.

But  i dont know how to find the ipaddress and hostname of http://hg.openjdk.java.net.

From another S10 system, i could be able to download the source.  i checked `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/resolve.conf`. Both are same. When i copy the downloaded source to my system and tried to build it in my system, am getting some timestamp error in hotfolder:

```
WARNING: You are using cc version 5.13 and should be using version 5.10.
Set ENFORCE_CC_COMPILER_REV=5.13 to avoid this warning.
/opt/csw/bin//gmake: invalid option -- /
/opt/csw/bin//gmake: invalid option -- c
/opt/csw/bin//gmake: invalid option -- c
/opt/csw/bin//gmake: invalid option -- 8
/opt/csw/bin//gmake: invalid option -- /
/opt/csw/bin//gmake: invalid option -- a
/opt/csw/bin//gmake: invalid option -- /
/opt/csw/bin//gmake: invalid option -- c
Usage: gmake [options] [target] ...
Options:
  -b, -m                      Ignored for compatibility.
  -B, --always-make           Unconditionally make all targets.
  -C DIRECTORY, --directory=DIRECTORY
                              Change to DIRECTORY before doing anything.
  -d                          Print lots of debugging information.
  --debug[=FLAGS]             Print various types of debugging information.
  -e, --environment-overrides
                              Environment variables override makefiles.
  -E STRING, --eval=STRING    Evaluate STRING as a makefile statement.
  -f FILE, --file=FILE, --makefile=FILE
                              Read FILE as a makefile.
  -h, --help                  Print this message and exit.
  -i, --ignore-errors         Ignore errors from recipes.
  -I DIRECTORY, --include-dir=DIRECTORY
                              Search DIRECTORY for included makefiles.
  -j [N], --jobs[=N]          Allow N jobs at once; infinite jobs with no arg.
  -k, --keep-going            Keep going when some targets can't be made.
  -l [N], --load-average[=N], --max-load[=N]
                              Don't start multiple jobs unless load is below N.
  -L, --check-symlink-times   Use the latest mtime between symlinks and target.
  -n, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon
                              Don't actually run any recipe; just print them.
  -o FILE, --old-file=FILE, --assume-old=FILE
                              Consider FILE to be very old and don't remake it.
  -O[TYPE], --output-sync[=TYPE]
                              Synchronize output of parallel jobs by TYPE.
  -p, --print-data-base       Print make's internal database.
  -q, --question              Run no recipe; exit status says if up to date.
  -r, --no-builtin-rules      Disable the built-in implicit rules.
  -R, --no-builtin-variables  Disable the built-in variable settings.
  -s, --silent, --quiet       Don't echo recipes.
  --no-silent                 Echo recipes (disable --silent mode).
  -S, --no-keep-going, --stop
                              Turns off -k.
  -t, --touch                 Touch targets instead of remaking them.
  --trace                     Print tracing information.
  -v, --version               Print the version number of make and exit.
  -w, --print-directory       Print the current directory.
  --no-print-directory        Turn off -w, even if it was turned on implicitly.
  -W FILE, --what-if=FILE, --new-file=FILE, --assume-new=FILE
                              Consider FILE to be infinitely new.
  --warn-undefined-variables  Warn when an undefined variable is referenced.

This program built for i386-pc-solaris2.10
Report bugs to <bug-make@gnu.org>
gmake[5]: *** [/export/home/preethi/buildopenjdk/check8/hotspot/make/solaris/makefiles/top.make:84: ad_stuff] Error 2
gmake[4]: *** [/export/home/preethi/buildopenjdk/check8/hotspot/make/solaris/Makefile:225: product] Error 2
gmake[3]: *** [Makefile:217: generic_build2] Error 2
gmake[2]: *** [Makefile:167: product] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [HotspotWrapper.gmk:45: /export/home/preethi/buildopenjdk/check8/build/solaris-x86-normal-server-release/hotspot/_hotspot.timestamp] Error 2
gmake: *** [/export/home/preethi/buildopenjdk/check8//make/Main.gmk:109: hotspot-only] Error 2
```

Following steps from:
https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/raw-file/tip/README-builds.html

System spec:
SunOS pkg.oracle.com 5.10 Generic_150401-16 i86pc i386 i86pc

1) If we add any ipaddress and host in /etc/hosts whether the problem will get resolved?

2) Why the copied source is not working in another S10?

In /etc/hosts Added 137.254.56.60 openjdk.java.net. But same error. From my system am not able to ping openjdk.java.net. no answer from 137.254.56.60. Am new to solaris and not very familiar with proxy settings. Can anyone please help.

Comment: In /etc/hosts Added 137.254.56.60 openjdk.java.net. But same error. From my system am not able to ping openjdk.java.net. no answer from 137.254.56.60.                                        Am new to solaris and not very familiar with proxy settings. Can anyone please help.

Comment: You can edit the question to add / modify it, don't add new info to the comments. It eventually becomes impossible to read / understand.